# Mail sent message comes but mail does not appear in inbox or spam?

Tags: php, email

Below is my mail code.
when php script will execute below sent alert message shows on screen but mail not received in inbox or spam. I am not getting where i m wrong? Please anybody can help me?

```
               $from_mail = "tdiesel.dinpl.com/new";
                /* Email functionality */

                $to = "m.ajinkya@drushti.in";        
                $subject = "Registration Complete";
                $message = "<br><br>Following are the account details.<br><br>";

                $message .= "<table border='1'>";

                $message .= "<tr>";
                $message .= "<td><b>Customer Name :</b></td><td>$dealer_username</td>";
                $message .= "</tr>";

                $message .= "<tr>";
                $message .= "<td><b>Password :</b></td><td>$dealer_password</td>";
                $message .= "</tr>";

                $message .= "</table>";

                $message .= "<br>";    
                $message .= "<br>Regards,<br>";
                $message .= "Team| Trident Diesel Pvt. LTD.<br>";
                $message .= "Web- www.tdiesel.dinpl.com/new<br>"; 
                $message .= "Contact – +91- 20-25290018<br>";                                                
                $headers = "From: $from_mail" . "\r\n";
                $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
                $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

                /* Send mail function for Merchant */
                $mail_send = mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
                if($mail_send)
                {
                    echo "<script>alert('Sent')</script>";
                }
                else
                {
                    echo "<script>alert('Not Sent')</script>";
                }
```

Comment: And you have SMTP server configured?

Comment: Are you working on local environment ?

Comment: no sir, i am working on live server

Comment: Try PHPmailer of something, it has more debugging features

Comment: now its working sir thank you..

Comment: Good to hear it's working. Please share what was the issue so that we can learn from this.